# Wrong path in Silex templates

Tags: symfony, twig, silex

I am trying to display my portfolio page, this works fine:

```
// Works
$app->get('/works', function () use ($app) {
        try {
       $yamlFile = file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/../data/work.web.yml');
       $works = Yaml::parse($yamlFile);
       return $app['twig']->render('works.twig',array(
        'pageTitle' => 'Works',
        'works' => $works,
        ));
           } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $e;
        }
})->bind('works');
```

But when add a parameter to router

```
// Works
$app->get('/works/{folio}', function ($folio) use ($app) {

        try {
       $yamlFile = file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/../data/work.'.$folio.'.yml');
       $works = Yaml::parse($yamlFile);

       return $app['twig']->render('works.twig',array(
        'pageTitle' => 'Sample '. $folio,
        'works' => $works,
        ));
           } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $e;
        }

});
```

The paths inside the templates are messed up, e.g:
now image paths became: `web/works/js/jquery.js` 404 (Not Found) instead `web/js/jquery.js`, images became: `web/works/galeria` instead `web/galeria` (as in first example).

How to fix the url ?

UPDATE:
If I change to `$app->get('/{folio}', function ($folio) use ($app) {`, paths are again fine but 
why can't it properly keeppath  'works/{folio}'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

In your template replace your relative paths with:

{{ app.request.basepath }}/your/path/js

Answer (score 7):

From the [Silex cookbook](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/cookbook/assets.html) you can add a filter to get the correct URL of your public assets, regardless of whichever path you are at on the site.

Add this after you've registered all the Service Providers you're using.

[Example in production here](https://github.com/archfizz/2009/blob/master/web/index.php#L28)

```
$app['twig'] = $app->share($app->extend('twig', function($twig, $app) {
    $twig->addFunction(new \Twig_SimpleFunction('asset', function ($asset) use ($app) {
        return sprintf('%s/%s',
            $app['request']->getBasePath(),
            ltrim($asset, '/')
        );
    }));

    return $twig;
}));
```

This example above is different to the one on the cookbook.

Now you can use it like:

```
{{ asset('js/jquery.js') }}
```

Comment: Thank you Adam, I need to further study the solution you proposed. To be honest I have the feeling of being a bit hacky. Indeed in my layout.twig I used relative paths: js/scripts.js.